# remove hyperlinks from tweets using hive

Tags: hadoop, twitter, hive

I am new in the field of big data and just started learning things. 
I have a tweets table in hive and in its text field, many records contain hyperlinks. I want to remove those hyperlinks but I am not able to do it. As charindex and other sql function for this purpose are not supported in hive, even after searching a lot I was not able to find any clue. I tried to do it with regexp_replace but its giving me 'index out of range' error which means I might not be writing the correct regexp.
here is my query for that 
`SELECT text, regexp_replace (text, '(https.*)', '') FROM tweets;`
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`regexp_replace` is a suitable approach, but your regular expression would be interpreted as "replace everything after the first occurrence of `https` with an empty string".  You do not need the parenthesis in this case, and your regexp pattern needs to more completely define the pattern of the URL you want to remove, likely by looking for the first whitespace character following https. Note that regexps are "greedy" by default so a pattern such as `https.*` (with a space after the `.*`) will look for the *longest* string within `text` Starting with http sand ending with a space.  Change this by adding a ? to the wildcard pattern, like `https.*?`.  Also, keep in mind that the URL may not have a space at the end in all cases, may or may not be https, but certainly will include a `//:`.  Use a site such a Rubular to work on your regexp, and then add to your query when you have it working.

Finally, it's likely that you should not put a space after the function so instead of `regexp_replace (...` do `regexp_replace(...`

Comment: thank you, with your provided Rubular reference I was able to refine my regular expression and successfully removed the hyperlinks.